# Ambiguity between column alias and another column's name

Tags: sqlite, ambiguous

I have got some tables with overlapping column names and I want to combine those columns into one column with the same name as alias, e.g.

```
select a.name || " " || b.name as name from a join b
```

This works fine. However, if I want to order them, e.g.

```
order by lower(name) asc
```

I get the error `ambiguous column name: name`, because sqlite doesn't know whether to use `a`'s, `b`'s or the selection's `name` column. My question is whether it is possible to specifically chose the selection's `name` column (without giving it a different alias)? Maybe there is some nice `<keyword>` such that `<keyword>.name` results in the selection's `name` column. Or is there really no better solution than

```
with tmp as (select tmp_a.name || " " || tmp_b.name as name from tmp_a join tmp_b)
select name from tmp order by lower(name) asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the use of the CTE or a subquery is not a good solution.
If you don't like them, the only way to do it is to repeat the expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select a.name || ' ' || b.name as name 
from a join b
on ......
order by lower(a.name || ' ' || b.name)
```

Comment: At least that's a prettier solution than subqueries (if the aliased column is simple). Thank you :)